# Kotlin jacoco coverage issue

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, jacoco

I have the following coverage report from jacoco:

[image]

This is happening after upgrading Kotlin from 1.6.10 to 1.6.20

What is the reason for this, and how can I avoid it?
It seems the coverage report is simply wrong.

Comment: Are you testing the case where `message.externalReference = null`?

Comment: Yes, that's why the line ?: Uni.createFrom().nullItem() is green.

Comment: That's true. Are you testing any case where it throws an exception?